# Trouble Processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class"

Tags: java, android

I'm starting out a new Android project that. The project is referencing one third-party JAR that in turn references 4 other jars:

```
ws-commons-java5-1.0.1.jar
ws-commons-util-1.0.2.jar
xmlrpc-client-3.1.3.jar
xmlrpc-common-3.1.3.jar
```

As far as I can tell, I think these 4 jars are standard Java classes I think. Anyways, I have all five of these jars (the 4 above + the 1 third party jar) in my Build Path. When I attempt to run my Android app, I get:

```
Dx 
trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2012-03-21 23:05:05 - MyApp ] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-03-21 23:05:05 - MyApp ] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I'm not sure what to do here. It's like it's asking me if I'm trying to build a core-library, which I'm not. I'm just trying to use these JARs in my project. Is there another way I should be referencing these JARs in my project? The error makes it sound like my project is going to randomly stop working for someone someday.

This is all very confusing. Any clues on how to properly proceed?

Answer (score 1):

There are some similiar problem reports on SO (with other classes but the same type of message  ) and hidden in one comment to a [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637707/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1) I found a pointer to a solution on an external site:

[Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class](http://www.coderanch.com/t/539779/Android/Mobile/Ill-advised-or-mistaken-usage)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that ws-commons-java5-1.0.1.jar is a reimplementation of part of the core Java library.  Android doesn't allow you to replace core libraries.

The good news is that ws-commons-java5 should only be necessary for java 1.4 or below, and Android includes the classes from java 1.5 that it replaces.  You should therefore be able to just remove this file from your project and it should work...

Comment: Ah okay I didn't consider that. I will try that and report back. Thanks!