# Android Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.scxml.env.jexl.JexlContext'

Tags: android, jexl, apache-commons-scxml

I'm using apache commons SCXML to define a state machine my Android app.  In my Android Studio project, I've added the following in the dependencies section of my build.gradle file:

```
compile 'commons-scxml:commons-scxml:0.9'
compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-jexl:2.1.1'
```

Unlike the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286760/apache-commons-scxml-cannot-find-jexlcontext), I cannot add xalan as it tries to overwrite Android system files, leading to [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816768/trouble-processing-javax-xml-xmlconstants-class).
I then clicked the 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' button, and the commons-scxml and commons-jexl files showed up in the "external dependencies" section of my project.

However, when I run my app, I still get this error:

```
Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.scxml.env.jexl.JexlContext', referenced from method org.apache.commons.scxml.env.AbstractStateMachine
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need `org.apache.commons:commons-jexl:1.1` as a dependency.